# Unable to coerce a :string to :datetime

Tags: java, spring, mule, netsuite

I am unable to use Mulesoft DataWeave to effectively transform a Date to a DateTime. For some reason, Mulesoft is treating the Date as a String.

What can I do to fix this issue and convert the date properly? The format I am attempting to go from is **yyyy-mm-dd** to **mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss**.

**Error:**

> Cannot coerce a :string to a :datetime, caused by :Text '2019-03-08'
>   could not be parsed at index 2.

**DataWeave**

```
DateCustomFieldRef__custentity_icims_legacy_f_next_renewal: flowVars.SalesforceAccount.Contract_End_Date__c as :datetime {format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"}
```

In the example above, **flowVars.SalesforceAccount.Contract_End_Date__c is a DATE**, and **DateCustomFieldRef__custentity_icims_legacy_f_next_renewal is a Date_time** in NetSuite.

Answer (score 1):

As per Mule [Type Coercion Table](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-types#type-coercion-table) :date to :date time Coercion not possible. You have to append time something like below to get expected result. As time will be default 00:00:00

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
("2017-02-15" ++ "00:00:00" )as :localdatetime  {format: "yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss"} as :string {format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"}
```

HTH